# The condition for the products of linear maps to be injective.

Tags: linear-algebra

There are n linear maps. Let us denote them by $S_1, S_2,.....,S_n$. Assume $S_1.S_2......S_n$ makes sense (products of linear maps). My question is that, am I right if I say that the sufficient condition for $S_1.S_2......S_n$ to be injective is, if Sn is injective?

My reasoning:-

If $S_n$ is injective then Null $S_n$ is {0} so if I can show that Null $S_1.S_2......S_n$ is also {0} then $S_1.S_2.....S_n$ is injective!

In order to do so, let us take a vector u in the domain of $S_n$ and assume $S_1.S_2....S_n(u)$=0. This implies that u=0 since Sn is injective Therefore, if $S_1.S_2.....S_n(u)$=0 then u=0 which means Null $S_1.S_2.....S_n$={0} so $S_1.S_2.....S_n$ is injective.

This further implies that even if $S_1, S_2,....,S_{n-1}$ is not injective, as long as the last term ($S_n$) is injective, the product $S_1, S_2,....,S_{n}$ is injective.

I hope someone could point out my mistake if I am wrong. I haven't seen anyone trying to prove if a function is injective in such a way so I think I may be wrong.

Btw here is the original question that I tried to solve using the method I shared above:-[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the product of linear maps?

Comment: Product as in composition of two functions @Michael Albanese

Comment: Compositions of injective functions are injective.

Comment: @Yorch "Makes sense" in this context means "is conformable for multiplication/composition"

Comment: @BenGrossmann then it is a sufficient condition, isn't it ?

Comment: @Yorch It's not.

Comment: So then problem 6 is false?

Comment: @Yorch It is sufficient for all maps $S_i$ to be injective, as the problem states. It is insufficient for only the right-most map to be injective, which is the condition that OP is asking about.

Comment: Note that $S_1,\ldots, S_{n-1}$ can be arbitrary and $S_n $the identity -- you don't mean to say that arbitrary $S_1\cdot\ldots \cdot S_{n-1}$ is injective, do you?

Comment: Oh I didn't read it correctly since that version makes $0$ sense lol :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong. $S_1 \cdots S_{n-1}S_n(u) = 0$ whenever $S_n(u) \in \ker(S_1 \cdots S_{n-1})$.

As an example, consider
$$
S_1 = \pmatrix{1&0&0}, \quad S_2 = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1\\0&0}.
$$

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Did you leave out some words?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct. Ben has already given you a counterexample. The problem in your logic lies with this statement:

> let us take a vector $u$ in the domain of $S_n$ and assume $S_1S_2\ldots S_n(u)=0$. This implies that $u=0$ since $S_n$ is injective.

It is entirely possible for $S_n u$ to be non-zero, and be part of $\ker S_1 S_2 \ldots S_{n-1}$. So, even though $S_n u \neq 0$, we still have $S_1 S_2 \ldots S_{n-1}(S_n u) = 0$.

As it turns out, the converse is true. If $S_1 S_2 \ldots S_n$ is injective, then $S_n$ must be injective! This is because, if we have $S_n u = 0$, then applying $S_1 S_2 \ldots S_{n-1}$ to both sides, we get $S_1 S_2 \ldots S_n u = 0$, which has only the trivial solution.

Comment: I see. Thank you for pointing out where I was wrong.